# How to add a Heroku deployed API to Vercel image optimization entries

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js, vercel

My front-end is deployed on Vercel, and the back-end on Heroku.

How should I add the API endpoint to my `next.config.js` file, in order to show my images?

What I've tried:

`herokuapp.com`

`my-api-link.herokuapp.com`

`my-api-link.herokuapp.com/uploads` (path for my static files)

I've tried to add `https://` prefix to the entry as well.

Is there something else that I've missed like a specific optimizer from Heroku?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your `next.config.js` setup?

Comment: `module.exports = {
    images: {
      domains: ['assets.vercel.com', 'localhost', 'herokuapp.com'],
    },
  }`

Comment: Do you get any error in the terminal when navigating to a page where an image should be loaded?

Comment: yes, from the Bad request
    INVALID_IMAGE_OPTIMIZE_REQUEST

Comment: From Next.js side, adding `my-api-link.herokuapp.com` to the `domains` array in the images config should be enough. If you're getting an error for the image request that means something's wrong with the request itself (maybe the image URL is not correct?).

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's not the case, locally it works. Finding tons of issues related to images on Heroku

Comment: Having same issue, but with AWS. Did you find a fix?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. works locally and not on production

Answer (score 1):

I too was getting the 400 INVALID_IMAGE_OPTIMIZE_REQUEST errors on my vercel deployment but not locally.

Fixed by adding an image loader https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader

```
import Image from 'next/image'

const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
  return `https://example.com/${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`
}

const MyImage = (props) => {
  return (
    <Image
      loader={myLoader}
      src="me.png"
      alt="Picture of the author"
      width={500}
      height={500}
    />
  )
}
```